# How to find root domain given a child domains in R / Python

Tags: python, r

Given a certain child domain (e.g. cardinals.mlb.com), I need to find the root domain (e.g. mlb.com).
Can this be done in Python or R?

I am not looking for Regex solutions because I have a list of 10k child domains and the way in which child domains are defined varies and there are no clear patterns in the words I would need to remove, e.g.:

- cardinals.mlb.com
- mlb.com/dbacks

Another example. I would want to find fabrikam.com from any other domain listed in the picture.

[image]

Comment: can you show examples with the forward slash?

Comment: Also give these examples as text not as an image. We would like to reproduce the work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```r
x <- c("cardinals.mlb.com","mlb.com/dbacks", "a.b.c.com", "a.com.org/this/that?bla=bla")

y <- sub("/.*$", "", x)
stringr::str_extract(y, "[^\\.]+\\.[^\\.]+$")
#> [1] "mlb.com" "mlb.com" "c.com"   "com.org"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>